# Syntax to combine media query with a qualifying selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, media-queries

In our current design, form elements get styled differently on a mobile device:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 759px) {
    form label {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    /*There's more...*/
}
```

Given the limited screen space, we're basically forcing a vertical form layout (#3-4 in this [classic uxmatters link](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php)).

<strike>Because some form labels have to be insanely verbose</strike> For sensible reasons, we now want to apply this style to *some* desktop forms, i.e. outside of scope of the media query. This, however, is invalid SASS syntax:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 759px), .vertical-form {
    /*...*/
}
```

How can the ruleset be applied on output within the media query **and** to `.vertical-form form label` (or, ideally, `form.vertical-form label`) elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Media queries are not selectors, they are special language constructs.  You can't combine them with anything other than media queries.  You will have to use a mixin to do what you're asking for because extends don't work across media queries either.

```
@mixin vertical-form {
    label {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 759px) {
    form {
        @include vertical-form;
    }
}

.vertical-form {
    @include vertical-form;
}
```

Comment: +1, makes sense, although I was hoping for something... more sassy :) Since the pre-processor already allows for [media queries to be nested inside css rules](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#media), I thought it would be reasonable for write-time flexibility would extend to my scenario.